# Obtener las dimensiones de una imagen en Javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Se puede con JavaScript obtener el tamaño de la imagen? es decir si está en un elemento web `image` con `width` y `height` se obtiene lo que ocupa a pantalla, pero me interesa saber cual es su tamaño real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
foto=new Image();
foto.src="Imagen.jpg";
document.images[0].src=foto.src;
ancho=foto.width;
alto=foto.height;

alert(ancho)
alert(alto)
</script>
```

Eso igual te sirve

Answer (score 5):

Desde HTML5 tienes disponibles los atributos **naturalWidth** y **naturalHeight**: [Fuente](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element)

#### Ejemplo

```
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/de/c2/3a/dec23ae0053c5b58175898dcfe2e7210.jpg" width="300" height="300">

<script>
    var img = document.querySelector('img');
    var altoDefinido = img.height; // 300
    var altoOriginal = img.naturalHeight; // 600
    var anchoDefinido = img.width; // 300
    var anchoOriginal = img.naturalWidth; // 600
</script>
```

Comment: Sería muy interesante poner un ejemplo mínimo, para conocer la estructura de uso, si no podría considerarse un comentario en vez de una respuesta.